# Get aspect ratio from HLS video stream

Tags: android, http-live-streaming, exoplayer, mediainfo

I need to improve my app to keep aspect ratio for video streams. Sometimes resolution is not in right ratio so I need to lean on aspect ratio written in media info. To play videos I'm using Exo Player 1. I can't find way to read aspect ratio from media info.

Has anyone done this before?

Comment: Listening to onVideoSizeChanged you can get the video width and height... https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/SimpleExoPlayer.VideoListener.html

Comment: @Idan I know that, but as I said resolution is not always right. I need to get the Aspect Ratio written in media info.

Comment: Check this out, might be related. https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/656

Comment: @Idan Thanks for the effort, but this is not the thing I'm looking for. I just need to read the ratio from media info. My problem with resolution is not connected to the app. The problem is in source so I need to fix it manually.